# Flutter package for message and notification Says RemoteMessage class is not define says

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Please anyone should help me out am new to flutter and am trying to use the notification Flutter and messaging Plugin but it says the Class RemoteMessage message is not define,[image]